# Is QOpenGLFunctions compatible with QGLWidget and QGLFramebufferObject?

Tags: qt, opengl

My OpenGL game currently uses Qt5, GLEW and the "old" QGLWidget + QGLFramebufferObjects to render. I wanted to get rid of GLEW, so I made my classes inherit from QOpenGLFunctions and initialize it in their constructors. The actual problem is that, despite successful init, my game now segfaults when rendering.

So, is it even possible to use QOpenGLFunctions with this "old" Qt4-style graphics stack or should I move to the modern Qt5 stack?

Comment: Not sure if there are problems with the "old" stack, but some things to try: ensure that you've called `initializeOpenGLFunctions()` on the functions instance.  Make sure that you call this function when an OpenGL context is current.  It's also worthwhile to check that the context format is correct (i.e., that it has the correct OpenGL version number).

Answer (score 0):

Answer to myself: Yes, it's compatible and works fine.

The root-cause for the crash was that I still accidentally #included GLEW in one of my files and bad things happened. The old Qt4-style graphics stack doesn't warn about this, but the new does.